# How to create a folder in rootfolder in Android

Tags: java, android, directory

As you can see in ss, some apps have created their own folders in my phone root folder.

So that means it's possible, but I couldn't find a way to do this.

[image]

Tried this but didn't work,

```
File folder = new File("/myfolder");
boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdir();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Java.IO.File folder = new Java.IO.File(
       Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, "dalisto/cache");
folder.Mkdir ();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get put the path to sdcard first, like this:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfolder");
folder.mkdir();
```

You don't need to check if folder exists, as mkdir() will just do nothing (and return false) in that case.

Comment: No, Actually I don't want to write on sdcard, it's internal storage.

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() returns the "primary" external storage, which usually is the internal storage (device specific afaik). There is no way to explicitly access the internal storage.